# How to add - in particular column in Dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below mentioned dataframe (Data_1) :

```
Type      cal    cal2     cal3     cal4
PER-11    125    148      177      198
PER-12    125    148      177      198
PER-13    125    148      177      198
PER-14    125    148      177      198
PER-15    125    148      177      198
PER-16    125    148      177      198
```

I want to add "-" in column `cal` and `cal3` but upto 3 cells only.

Required Dataframe:

```
Type      cal    cal2     cal3     cal4
PER-11     -     148       -      198
PER-12     -     148       -      198
PER-13     -    148        -      198
PER-14    125    148      177      198
PER-15    125    148      177      198
PER-16    125    148      177      198
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `replace` and specify the `list` with the index that we want to replace and as it is multi-column replacement, use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(cal, cal3), funs(replace(., 1:3, '-')))
#     Type cal cal2 cal3 cal4
#1 PER-11   -  148    -  198
#2 PER-12   -  148    -  198
#3 PER-13   -  148    -  198
#4 PER-14 125  148  177  198
#5 PER-15 125  148  177  198
#6 PER-16 125  148  177  198
```

Answer (score 2):

Using R base:

```
> df1[1:3, c("cal", "cal3") ] <- "-"
> df1
    Type cal cal2 cal3 cal4
1 PER-11   -  148    -  198
2 PER-12   -  148    -  198
3 PER-13   -  148    -  198
4 PER-14 125  148  177  198
5 PER-15 125  148  177  198
6 PER-16 125  148  177  198
```

Comment: Umm this is way I will use :-)